# Optimal Riak storage strategy

Tags: database, json, nosql, sensors, riak

I'm planning to use Riak for storing some sensor data, but sensors are connected to different users. My plan is to make a structure like this:
Bucket = user id
key = time, new key each minute (or two minutes maybe)

When I say a new key each minute, the readings are not always continuous and are not real time, but they are being uploaded later. They are recorded at certain periods of the day. The frequency of metering is quite high, 250 samples a second. If I make a new key for each measurement, I will get an explosion of keys very fast and I don't think it will do good for performance. Besides that, I do not really need to know the precise number at each given moment, I will use them more sequentially in a period (values from minute N to minute M).

So I'm thinking of "grouping" the results for each minute, and storing them like that as some JSON.

Does this strategy look feasible?

Also, I'm thinking about using LevelDB as the storage engine, just to be on the safe side as far as RAM usage goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower keys count seems better for me then key for each event. How would you use this data later?

If data is intended for further analyze, leveldb and secondary indexes allow you to pick a data for certain period (if your keys somehow ordered, datetime for instance) in a mapreduce job (with additional efforts it could be done in a background).
Also leveldb do not store all keys in memory, it is good for continuously growing dataset, if you plan to store all the data forever.

If your application depends on predictable latency and need fixed amount of data per query It better to group data like application wants (for sample all keys for a 10 min in one object).

One more concern is total object size, as riak docs says it better not exceed 10mb size for single object.

Comment: As I said, the data will be read from in parts as in from one time, to another. Each value with the key (time) which fits between two times should be read. If there will be some processing (not in first time) it would probably be done in the same way, find a pattern that emerges between two times. The values, once saved, will not grow later. I don't think they will be over 10MB, that is really a lot of text. 
I'm not completely clear on secondary indices and how are they used, for now. Thank you, it sounds like I was planning.
One more thing, how does Riak compare time in the keys?

Comment: Riak generaly is key/value storage, however there special functionality like secondary indices and mapreduce which allow to do more the one query at the time.
2i allow fetch data from start key till end key. All keys which lexicographically between them will be picked